# Is there a way to mark TODO complete in Android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, todo

I'm trying to track **TODO**s in Android studio.

Is there a way to mark them 'complete' without simply deleting them?

Comment: Change the word `TODO` to `DONE`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch This is an answer I think. Simple yet complete.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, a good suggestion. (And that's what I'll probably end up doing.) But since TODO is special comment, I was hoping there is another special comment or some means of handling TODO completion.

Comment: @Ross, agreed, it is a simple, complete answer.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch but then it wouldnt be tracked.

Comment: @NullByte08 Version control is for tracking changes over time and task management tools are for tracking tasks; what is the purpose of a `TODO` comment? What purpose to a `DONE` comment serve? Basically, what problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch There is a `TODO` option in Android Studio's tool window bar, which tracks all the TODOs. When you mark the comment as done, the TODO comment is removed from that list. Dario's answer gives us the option to mark the comment as done so it can be easily viewed in that list just besides other TODOs.

Comment: Its just easier for the user nothing much.

Comment: Can't we use the symbol `[x]` just before a TODO to mark it as done just like we do in GitHub?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The common convention is that when a `TODO` is done, then you delete it from the code.

Same with `FIXME` or `STOPSHIP`. (`STOPSHIP` might get picked up by CI servers and sets the build to **failed** until the comment is removed).

If you want to track progress of completed items, you have other tools available:

- Use a ticket system like [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org)
- Use a version control system like [GIT](http://www.git-scm.com) and submit one commit per fix
- Use a naming scheme (We use `// <shortname>/<date>: Fixes #<number of bug`)

Answer (score 23):

I extended the solution of setting a new pattern of `TODO` by adding a **MACRO** to making the process automatic.

[image: animation: replacing TODO with COMPLETED]

1. At first we have to have set a new pattern for `TODO` as I mentioned at the beginning.
2. Then we have to make a macro by executing the following steps:

   - Go to: *EDIT -> MACROS -> Start Macro Recording*
   - Since now your actions are recording by Android Studio. Set the cursor on the “TODO” word and press: Left **Alt + J** // *FOR MAC OS X:* **Ctrl + G** / **Shift + Ctrl + G** (TODO word will be highlighted)
     [See the screenshot #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT7AU.png)
   - Now **press the CAPS LOCK key button** to turn on CAPS LOCK (or use SHIFT button instead of CAPS LOCK for typing capital letters)
   - …and type **COMPLETED** (or other word which you used in your own TODO pattern)
     [See the screenshot #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBtl0.png)
   - Now **press the CAPS LOCK key button again** to turn off CAPS LOCK (or release the SHIFT button)
   - Go to: *EDIT -> MACROS -> Stop Macro Recording*
   - Enter a name for your macro
     [See the screenshot #3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Byidr.png)
3. Go to: *FILE -> SETTINGS -> KEYMAP* (If you can’t find it, use the search field)
   [See the screenshot #4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP2gM.png)
4. Add your own Keyboard Shortcut
   [See the screenshot #5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvxa3.png)
5. Click APPLY
6. THAT’S ALL! Set the cursor on `TODO` word in your code and press your preselected shortcut.

Comment: Half of the gif is attempting to prove you didn't touch the clipboard, but it did not prove that. I believe you though. :)

Answer (score 16):

in the -> **settings/editor/todo** and follow the steps. Write the name you'll use to replace "TODO" as the name of the new pattern for step 1.

[image: new todo patterns]

Comment: I mixed both answers from you & @Michał Dobrowolski. The result is amazing :) Thank you Guys :)